Instantiate a QgsElevationProfileWidget from Python
Is it possible to create a new Elevation Profile window from Python in QGIS 3.38?
(basically what the "Elevation Profile" view menu item does).
It is relatively easy to create a QgsElevationProfileCanvas cf. this test.
Yet the createNewElevationProfile from src/app/qgisapp.h does not seem to be exposed in Python.
I can use the action from the View Menu after the answer by @juliustoth)
action = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QAction, 'mActionElevationProfile')
action.trigger()

which actually creates a new Elevation Profile but as trigger() does not return anything I cannot handle the widget.
I can find the elevation profiles widgets with:
eprofiles = [
    c for c in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QWidget)
    if c.objectName() == "ElevationProfile"
]

but they are raw QWidget references so I think my problems come from the fact that QgsElevationProfileWidget is not exposed to python.

Try this in QGIS Python console:
action = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QAction, 'mActionElevationProfile')
action.trigger()

"mActionElevationProfile" is the objectName of the Action.

Thanks @juliustoth!
